# Retrieving Posts from Followed Users in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on developing a social media application, and I'm currently in the phase of displaying posts from all the users I'm following on the home page. For this, I need to retrieve all the data from the "confessions" collection of users who have specific UIDs (matching the UIDs in the "following" collection) in the "users" collection. I've researched CollectionGroup, but it doesn't seem to be suitable for this purpose. How can I write a query for this, or what changes can I make to the Firebase structure? I'm open to any advice. Thank you in advance.

[image: users collection]

[image: confessions collection]

**EDIT**: I solved the problem, and I'd like to explain how I did it, maybe it can be helpful to someone in the future. First, I used collectionGroup, which is used to retrieve data from all collections with the same name in Firestore, making it ideal for fetching the confession lists of each user. However, in my case, I needed to fetch the confession lists of the followed individuals, so I added some constraints while retrieving the data with collectionGroup. Here, the userId of the person making the confession becomes the 'fromUserId,' so I collected the IDs in 'following' into a list and used 'whereIn' to fetch confessions with 'fromUserId' matching the IDs in that list. My code looks like this:

```
        val followingCollection = database.collection("users").document(currentUserUid).collection("following")

        followingCollection.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
                val followedUserIds = querySnapshot.documents.map { it.id }

                val confessionsList = mutableListOf<Confession>()

                if (followedUserIds.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val confessionsCollectionGroup = database.collectionGroup("confessions")

                    confessionsCollectionGroup
                        .whereIn("fromUserId", followedUserIds)
                        .limit(limit)
                        .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                        .get()
                        .addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
                                val confessions = querySnapshot.toObjects(Confession::class.java)
                                confessionsList.addAll(confessions.distinctBy { it.id })
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Do a separate subcollection query for each user id, then merge the results of each query into a single list in your application
2. Put the user ID in a field in each and every confession document, and use that new field as a filter in a collection group query on confessions.

Comment: Hello, I updated the question. I arrived at the answer in a way similar to the second point. Thank you for your interest.